# How to display an array consisting of serialised data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, serialization

I am fetching a record from the database which looks like this.

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [creation_time] => 1497617542590 
        [is_marks_range_visible] => 1 
        [is_description_visible] => 
        [is_grade] => 
        [classes] => 
        [is_grade_visible] => 
        [grades] => 
        [is_points] => 1
        [is_description] => 
        [school_id] => 28
        [is_points_visible] => 1
        [name] => CBSE Test
        [id] => 30
        [grade_system_json] => [{"id":0,"min_marks":85,"max_marks":100,"grade":null,"description":null,"points":10.0},{"id":0,"min_marks":80,"max_marks":89,"grade":null,"description":null,"points":9.0}]
        [board] => CBSE
    )
    [status] => success
)
```

I managed to fetch the data and display it on the page, but having problems iterating through the `grade_system_json` data. I want to iterate through that serialised data.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you are looking for..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you trying to access `grade_system_json` ???

Comment: Please add some code snipet that you have tried yet ?

Comment: yes i am trying to access grade_system_json

Comment: i tried this print_r($obj['data']['grade_system_json'])..
i get the following
[{"id":0,"min_marks":85,"max_marks":100,"grade":null,"description":null,"points":10.0},{"id":0,"min_marks":80,"max_marks":89,"grade":null,"description":null,"points":9.0}]

Comment: how to i iterate through it...

Comment: You'll have to decode it, check this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/617/json/2018/decoding-a-json-string#t=201706170916583974208) for more information.

Comment: Use `$xdecode = json_decode($array["data"]["grade_system_json"]);print_r($xdecode)`

Comment: it did not work.. but thank you for taking your time and helping me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the JSON you have stored in that `grade_system_json` key, and then you'll have an array to iterate over. Assuming your data is stored in the variable `$obj`, it would look like this:

```
$arr = json_decode($obj["data"]["grade_system_json"], true);

foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    // output some values. Adapt as needed:
    echo "id: {$elem["id"]}, min_marks: {$elem["min_marks"]}\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Trincot.. that worked for me... it was exactly what i wanted...

Answer (score 0):

make a foretch loop that will run over the array and make an "if" condition of value == grade_system_json, do another foretch inside that will echo etch value

but seriously , i hope that you are not working in this messy way, the associate array you posted here is vary hard to read